# solution of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to proof this: 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}=\ln 2
\end{equation}
but I worked it out as follow:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} & =e^{\lambda}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} & =e^{\lambda}-1 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!} & =1-e^{-1}
\end{align*}

I do not know what to do? How can I proof the original question? Or the maybe the answer is not $\ln 2$.

Comment: Well, you PROVED that is in not $\ln2$, didn't you?

Comment: I think you added the factorial '!' sign

Comment: @Did , It is somehow a homework. I what to make sure that the answer is not $\ln 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!} \neq \ln 2
$$

You probably meant
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \ln 2
$$

Comment: The problem is, there is a factorial in denominator.

Comment: Then your solution is correct. The expression you gave is definitely not equal to $\ln 2$ (try numerical approximation if you're not sure; they differ by about 0.061).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just use $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n$$

Comment: This is a typical mistake you find spread all around the internet. You cannot just evaluate at $x=1$. It does work, but it is because of Abel's Theorem, and not just because of the equality.

Comment: Yes, but there is a factorial in denominator.

Comment: @m.akbari If there is a factorial in the denominator, you will not be able to prove that the sum converges to $\ln{2}$, in fact, since your particular sum that you describe is absolutely convergent, I'm not sure you can use a rearrangement of the terms to have it converge to $\ln{2}$

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can prove it by showing that the value which it is, is in fact another value than $\ln(2)$ .
So, by the exponential series the series has a value, say $a$ which is easy to determine. (Possibly you shall also say something about the convergence of the given series). Then you show, that $ a\ne \ln(2)$ ...